# asp.net repeater vertical and horizontal scrollbars and fixed header

Tags: c#, asp.net, horizontal-scrolling, asprepeater, fixed-header-tables

There seems to be a ton of confusion and unnecessary complexity around enabling scrollbars on browsers.

I have an asp.net app and I'm trying to display a queue made with an asp.net repeater.  The vertical scrollbar works no problem and as expected.  However to have a default horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the window (not on the div or any other element in the app, on the browser window) has proven to be a colossal pain, with no solution that I've been able to find.

How do I make sure that horizontal scrollbars are enabled on the browser?

Also, as a bonus question, how do I make the header of my repeater table fixed on the screen?  Code below.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ResultsTableRepeater" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="RepeaterTable" class="td-table-bordered" style="font-size: small>
                    <tr id="FixedHeader" >
                        <th>Change #</th>
                        <th>Change Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Change Sponsor</th>
                        <th>Clarity Id</th>
                        <th>Assigned To</th>
                        <th>Intake Received</th>
                        <th>Risk Rating</th>
                        <th>Risk Analysis Completed</th>
                        <th>Performance Testing?</th>
                        <th>PRA Status</th>
                        <th>Lab Request Status</th>
                        <th>Target Production Date</th>
                        <th>Overall Status</th>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style='<%#(Eval("AssignedTo").ToString() == "1" || Eval("AssignedTo").ToString() == "2")? "": "font-weight:bold; background-color:cornsilk" %>'>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ChangeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ChangeId") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="UpdateLink" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ChangeId", "http://dev.rlaninfrastructure.tdbank.ca/RCGViewForm?ChangeId={0}") %>' runat="server"><%# Eval("ChangeTitle") %></asp:HyperLink></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("ChangeDescription") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("ChangeSponsor") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("ClarityId") %></td>
                    <td><%# (Eval("EmployeeName").ToString() == string.Empty) ? "" : Eval("EmployeeName")%></td>
                    <td><%# ((DateTime)Eval("DateSubmitted")).ToShortDateString() %></td>
                    <td><%# (Eval("OverallRiskRating").ToString() == string.Empty) ? "Not Completed" : (Eval("OverallRiskRating").ToString() == "3") ? "High" : (Eval("OverallRiskRating").ToString() == "2") ? "Med" : "Low" %></td>
                    <td><%# (Eval("RiskAnalysisComplete").ToString() != string.Empty) ? ((DateTime)Eval("RiskAnalysisComplete")).ToShortDateString() : "Not Completed"%></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="PRALabel" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# (Eval("PRAComplete").ToString() == "1") ? "PRA Form Submitted" : (Eval("IsPCoERequired").ToString() == "1" 
                    || Eval("IsCanadianRetailBranch").ToString() == "1") ? "Yes" : "No" %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="PRACompleteLabel" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# (Eval("PRAComplete").ToString() == "1") ? "Completed" 
                              : ((Eval("IsPCoERequired").ToString() != "1" || Eval("IsCanadianRetailBranch").ToString() != "1") 
                              ? "Not Required" : "Pending") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabRequestedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("LabRequested").ToString() == "1") ? "Lab Requested" 
                                                                            : ((Eval("IsLabRequired").ToString() != "1") ? "Not Required" 
                                                                            : "Pending Lab Form Completion") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td><%# ((DateTime)Eval("TargetDate")).ToShortDateString() %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("OverallChangeStatus").ToString() == "1"? "In Progress" 
                            : Eval("OverallChangeStatus").ToString() == "2"? "Completed" 
                            : Eval("OverallChangeStatus").ToString() == "3" ? "Pending" 
                            : Eval("OverallChangeStatus").ToString() == "4"? "Under Review"
                            : Eval("OverallChangeStatus").ToString() == "5"? "On Hold"
                            : Eval("OverallChangeStatus").ToString() == "6"? "Rejected"  
                            : "" %>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: If you're looking to set the scrollbars to always on, try `<body style="overflow: scroll">` or `<body style="overflow-x: scroll">` for horizontal only.

Answer (score 0):

Provide overflow scroll whenever you want scroll in page.

To handle horizontal scroll with respect to header of repeater you can  use scroll of jquery

put div wrapper on table of header in repeater

```
<div id="divHeader" class="overflowhidden">

                            <table class="table-serviceline table table-hover table-bordered">
                                <tr class="child-header-dark child-header">
                                   ......
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Put another div on item template with below class

```
<div id="divItem" class="box-content overflowauto maxh">
<table>
.....
</table>
</div>
```

Now use below code for Jquery to maintain scroll based on content horizontal scroll.

```
 $(function () {
        $('#divItem').scroll(function () {
            $('#divHeader').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
        });
    });
```